# Shell scripting: Redirecting the STDERR shows the actual script

Tags: bash, shell, echo, stderr, cp

I am creating a script for the backup automation process and while doing so, in the script when I tried to redirect the STDERR to a .log file it redirects properly and when I tried to extract the log from that file, IT SHOWS THE ACTUAL SCRIPT. why is that?

Code:

```
LFB(){ #Local full backup
echo -e "\nBackup in progress. . .\n"
cp -rfp $srcpath/ $destpath > bkup.log 2&>1
set `tail -n 2 bkup.log`
echo -e "\nTransfered $2 $3 and the\c"
}
```

Comment: Maybe not related, but: Your `set` commands do not make any sense to me.  According to the bash man page, the `set` command has the syntax _set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [arg ...]_

Comment: Also, your usage of $1, $2 and $3 is suspicious. You use the parameters *only* in `echo` statements, but don't do anything with them. It would be helpful if you also showed how you invoke the script.

Comment: Okay the command should come like this ```cp -rfp $srcpath/ $destpath >bkup.log 2&>1```

here the ```set``` command is working fine now.

Comment: Hmmmmm, this is not related to either of my comments.

Comment: @user1934428 It looks to me like the `set` and `$2`, `$3` stuff is a really strange way of reading values from the file. Abiramsundar, I'd recommend learning to use the `read` command instead.

Comment: @Abiramsundar The script snippet you gave is not enough to tell what's going on; you need to include enough for someone else to run the script, and see the problem happen. But that doesn't mean include the entire script (especially since it probably depends on files and directories you have...). So make a copy of the script and start removing parts you don't think are necessary for the problem to happen. Test as you go, and if the problem vanishes, the part you just removed *is* part of the problem, so put it back. When it's trimmed to a minimum size, edit that into your question.

Comment: See our help section ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more suggestions and info. BTW, while trimming the script, you may figure out the problem yourself; if so, please let us know so we can close the question.

Comment: My guess is 1) When you say it "shows the script", what you are actually seeing is the output of the "set" command, which would output both shel variables and shell functions (like LBF);  I'm with @user1934428, that your `set` line does not make any sense to me either.   2) It should be `2>&1`, not `2&>1`

Comment: @GordonDavisson the code which I provided is a function which is called by some other function. Here what I am trying to do is, I am copying some files from one location to another location using ```cp``` command and also at the same time the output or error(s) from this command is getting redirected to a log file which is _bkup.log_ here. And after that, I am gathering the last 2 lines of the output or error from _bkup.log_ file using ```set``` command and lastly displaying the positional parameters of the ```set``` command using ```$2``` & ```$3``` in ```echo``` command.

Comment: @Abiramsundar : Your `set` commands neither gather something from the log, nor do they just display those positional parameters you are mentioning.

Comment: If the output from the `tail` command starts with a "`-`", `set` will treat what follows as shell options to set, which can cause really weird results. Possibly including what's going on here, but again without more info (i.e. a minimal, reproducible example) it's impossible to say if that's it. But in any case, `set` is the wrong way to do this.